# Repeat values with in the GROUP in SQL

Tags: hive

I am trying to repeat a row value in the subsequent rows with in GROUP. A Group can have one or more TAG. The requirement is to populate NEW_TAG in the row where the TAG is populated and in the subsequent rows until another TAG populated with in the same group  or we reach end of that GROUP.

```
Current Table      Required Table

GROUPID SEQ TAG    GROUPID SEQ TAG NEW_TAG
------- --- ----   ------- --- --- --------
1       1           1       1       
1       2           1       2       
1       3           1       3       
1       4   4       1       4   4   4
1       5           1       5       4
1       6           1       6       4
1       7           1       7       4
1       8           1       8       4
2       1           2       1       
2       2           2       2       
2       3           2       3       
2       4           2       4       
2       5   5       2       5   5   5
2       6           2       6       5
2       7           2       7       5
2       8           2       8       5
2       9   9       2       9   9   9
2      10           2      10       9
2      11           2      11       9
```

Comment: add a proper data sample and the expected  result ...and don't use image only but add  text data too

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    groupid,
    seq,
    tag,
    last_value(tag) ignore nulls over (
        partition by groupid
        order by seq
    ) as new_tag
from t
order by groupid, seq;

GRO SEQ TAG NEW_TAG
1   1    -   - 
1   2    -   - 
1   3    -   - 
1   4   4   4
1   5    -  4
1   6    -  4
1   7    -  4
1   8    -  4
2   1    -   - 
2   2    -   - 
2   3    -   - 
2   4    -   - 
2   5   5   5
2   6    -  5
2   7    -  5
2   8    -  5
2   9   9   9
2   10   -  9
2   11   -  9

19 rows selected.
```

Comment: @Samedi :- Thank you . But when I tried running this code I am getting the following error -  " Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 6:23 missing EOF at 'NULLS' near 'IGNORE' "

Comment: What is your version of Oracle?

Comment: Actually I am running this in HIVE. I thought the SQL functionalities are going to be same in Oracle and HIVE, that's why I selected Oracle in the tag.

Comment: That's a wrong assumption. SQL functionality varies across platforms. Something new like Hive is quite impoverished compared to Oracle (although that may change in the future). So please don't waste the time of the people people you're asking to help you: tag your questions with the precise product you need.